# Create filesystem in regular file using FreeBSD

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, disk-image

When using Linux, one can easily create a regular file of some size and then create a filesystem in it. How can one do the same thing when using FreeBSD?

I tried this:

```
root@:/tmp/test # newfs -U ~/disk
newfs: /root/disk: not a character-special device: No error: 0
newfs: no valid label found
```

I didn't find any relevant information on this (e.g.: "Use switch -i to allow the filesystem to be created on a regular file instead of only on a character device." on the (fairly short) man page of `newfs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the file; "1g" stands for one gigabyte:

```
truncate -s 1g disk.img
```

Attach the file as a virtual memory disk; this will print the allocated device name, eg "md0":

```
mdconfig disk.img
```

Create a filesystem on that memory disk:

```
newfs /dev/md0
```

And finally mount it:

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt
```

You can use `mdconfig -lv` to show currently attached memory disks.  Also note that the memory disk - md0 in this case, [link](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?md) - is a GEOM provider, so for all practical intents and purposes behaves as a disk.  Which means, if you do an image of a physical disk, and attach that image using mdconfig(8), GEOM will automatically probe partitions, so you'll get /dev/md0p1, /dev/md0p2 etc.  You can also use geli(8) to encrypt its contents, or create a zpool on them.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that when the file is attached, `mdconfig` will, by default, output the name of the device created (without the preceding `/dev`), for example: `md0`. This is useful if you are doing the thing in a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

## Linux

> Create the file.

`dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.ext3 bs=1024 count=131072`

> Create the filesystem

`mke2fs disk.ext3`

> Mount the new file

`mount disk.ext3 /mnt -o loop=/dev/loop0`

---

## FreeBSD

> Create the file.

`dd if=/dev/zero of=~/disk.img bs=1024 count=131072`

> Create the device /dev/md1

`mdconfig -a -t vnode -f ~/disk.img -u 0`
`bsdlabel -w /dev/md0`

> Create the filesystem

`newfs /dev/md0`

> Mount the new file

`mount /dev/md0 /mnt`

Comment: The questioner specifically asked how to do this on FreeBSD, not on Linux.

Comment: the only thing that might be lacking is mke2fs, this can be installed via "sysutils/e2fsprogs".   `cd /usr/ports/sysutils/e2fsprogs/ && make install clean`

Comment: No.  Your answer contains several Linuxisms and is outright wrong for FreeBSD.  Badly papering over just one of the Linuxisms does not improve it.

Comment: okay then added further newfs friendly instructions, better?

Comment: Is the `c` after `/dev/md0` intended in the 2 last occurrences? Because if I add it, I get the error message `newfs: /dev/md0c: could not find special device`. And I don't see why this file would exist. If I don't include the `c`, it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry.  Typo corrected.

Comment: @JdeBP - dunno if the edit added the bsd info, but I like seeing how to do it on the system I'm used to (Linux) and what is new to me (the bsd)